# Enable access to registry in WinForms application of C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

By default : Registry has been disabled 
So i get "registry editing has been disabled by your administrator"
In my application i want to let users access registry when the app runs and deny when app stops.
Looking forward for your advice on this.

Comment: Forgot to mention i want this for Windows XP SP2 And SP3 only.

Comment: You want to write a program that has *more* privileges than the admin?  Consider the possibility that Windows doesn't work that way.  Nor admins.  And what would happen, if this actually could work, when the user aborts the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow users to edit some registry settings that are normally not accessible, you need to use impersonation. I.e. you need to have your application run as a different user, one with more priviledges.

The easiest way to achieve this it to write a .net Windows Service that runs with higher priviledges. This service can still control what registry settings are allowed to change.
So your users start your Winforms app which communicates with your Service to do the actual changes in the registry.

This does require the user (or operations) to install the service on the machine with admin rights.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but can you please share some links / code ( atleast pseudo-code ) for such a .NET Windows Service running as a user at higher privileges.Thanks Again!

Comment: A windows service will always run with a service user.
Open Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services and take a look at the properties of a service.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677948(VS.85).aspx

How to write a windows service - Google: http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=c%23+windows+service&aq=f&aqi=g2g-c1g1g-c1g1g-c3g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=
The top answers will help you get started. It is really easy!

Comment: Adding a windows service for this reason only is a big overhead. Not to mention that only a user with administrative rites can install it.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your app runs on Vista or Win7 and you don't have access to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. In order to edit registry values in that area you need to add a manifest in your project and add this line to it:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: Forget to mention i want this for Windows XP SP2 And SP3 only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your admin has disabled access to *Regedit.exe* using the "Prevent access to registry editing tools" group policy setting — that's why you're getting that "Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator" message.

That does not affect access to the *registry*, though. Your application can still access and modify the registry (well, at least HKCU) using the [RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey%28VS.80%29.aspx) class, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use assembly attribute `RegistryPermissionAttribute()` above namespace

```
[assembly: RegistryPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, ViewAndModify = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER")]
//SecurityAction is enum having different security parameters
```